# How to send custom header from spring-cloud-stream (aws kinesis binder) to "legacy" spring integration consumer

Tags: spring-integration, spring-cloud-stream, spring-integration-aws

I have two applications - the first produces messages using spring-cloud-stream/function with the AWS Kinesis Binder, the second is an application that builds off of spring integration to consume messages.  Communicating between the two is not a problem - I can send a message from "stream" and handle it easily in "integration".

When I want to send a custom header, then there is an issue.  The header arrives at the consumer as an embedded header using the "New" format (Has an 0xff at the beginning, etc.) - See AbstractMessageChannelBinder#serializeAndEmbedHeadersIfApplicable in spring-cloud-stream.

However, the KinesisMessageDrivenChannelAdapter (spring-integration-aws) does not seem to understand the "new" embedded header form.  It uses EmbeddedJsonHeadersMessageMapper (See #toMessage) which cannot "decode" the message.  It throws a `com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'ÿ': was expecting (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')` because of the additional information included in the embedded header (0xff and so on).

I need to send the header across the wire (the header is used to route on the other side), so it's not an option to "turn off" headers on the producer.  I don't see a way to use the "old" embedded headers.

I'd like to use spring-cloud-stream/function on the producer side - it's awesome.  I wish I could redo the consumer, but...

I could write my own embedded header mapper that understands the new format (use EmbeddedHeaderUtils), and wire it into the KinesisMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.

Given the close relationship between spring-cloud-stream and spring-integration, I must be doing something wrong. Does Spring Integration have an OutboundMessageMapper that understands the new embedded form?

Or is there a way to coerce spring cloud stream to use a different embedding strategy?

I could use Spring Integration on the producer side. (sad face).

Any thoughts?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> understands the new format

It's not a "new" format, it's a format that Spring Cloud Stream created, originally for Kafka, which only added header support in 0.11.

> I could write my own embedded header mapper that understands the new format (use `EmbeddedHeaderUtils`), and wire it into the `KinesisMessageDrivenChannelAdapter`.

I suggest you do that, and consider [contributing it to the core Spring Integration Project](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/main/CONTRIBUTING.adoc) alongside the `EmbeddedJsonHeadersMessageMapper` so that it can be used with all technologies that don't support headers natively.